# Update index value using patch in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, database, patches

Currenty, order_id is set as unique and i want to set as the index. Please help me on this.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Abc\Xyz\Setup\Patch;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class RemoveIndex implements PatchInterface
{

    /**
     * @var SchemaSetupInterface
     */
    private $schemaSetup;

    public function __construct(
        SchemaSetupInterface $schemaSetup
    ) {
        $this->schemaSetup = $schemaSetup;
    }

    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        $connection = $this->schemaSetup->getConnection();
        $connection->addIndex(
            'table',
            $setup->getIdxName(
                'table',
                ['order_id'],
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX
            ),
            ['order_id'],
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX
        );
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create **db_schema.xml** under the **etc** directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="table_name" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Table Name">
        <index referenceId="USEYOUR_UNIQUE_INDEX_NAME" indexType="btree">
            <column name="order_id"/>
        </index>
    </table>
</schema>
```

[You can check here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/etc/db_schema.xml#L25)

Comment: I created the index in the same module and now i want to change the unique to index. because i tried this thing but it is not working.